# Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 - Error When Selecting New Release

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

Getting an exception when selecting a Release Template and choosing "New Release" on "Configure Apps" tab of RM for Visual Studio 2013 Client.

After clicking "New Release" a pop-up appears in the lower right corner of the screen with "Unhandled Exception" and red stop sign. Looking through Event Viewer, below is the stack trace.

Anyone else encountering the same error?

The only step in the Release Template is to copy files to a DEV server on the same subnet.

```
Message: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.: \r\n\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.PlatformHttpClient.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClientResponseRetriever.EndGetAsyncMemoryStreamFromResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult, IPlatformHttpClient platformHttpClient)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClientResponseRetriever.EndDownloadString(IAsyncResult asyncResult, IPlatformHttpClient platformHttpClient)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClient.EndPost(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Proxy.RestProxy.HttpRequestor.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetPostCaller>b__0(String url, String body)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Proxy.RestProxy.BaseDeploymentControllerServiceProxy.PopulateTaggedActivities(String workflowXml, Int32 environmentId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.Release.BuildReleaseStages(ReleasePath selectedReleasePath, XElement applicationVersion)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.Release.BringDataFromApplicationVersion()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.Release.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName, Boolean setDirty)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.PropertyChangedBase.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.Release.set_ApplicationVersionId(Int32 value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.ViewModel.ViewModels.ReleaseViewModel.Initialize(Int32 modelId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.ViewModel.ViewModels.ReleaseViewModel..ctor(String viewMode, Dictionary`2 popupParameters)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.ViewModel.ViewModels.ApplicationVersionsViewModel.CreateNewRelease(Int32 releaseTemplateId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.ViewModel.ViewModels.ApplicationVersionsViewModel.CreateRelease(XElement selectedItem)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.ViewModel.ViewModels.ApplicationVersionsViewModel.CreateNewRelease(Object selectedItems)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.ViewModel.Helpers.RelayCommand.Execute(Object parameter)
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
Category: General
Priority: -1
EventId: 0
Severity: Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was permissions related. Fixed by adding AD computer name in Release Management server users.